# Vertical Align absolute div content

Tags: html, css

Okay I've read the questions on here regarding vertical align with absolute positioning. However, none of them solves my problem.

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="package-container row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        Col 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="package-border"><img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/toolbox/images/package-bg-1.png"/></div>
        <div class="package-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <?php the_field('description'); ?>
        <?php if(get_field('special')) { ?>
            <div class="package-expries">
                Expires <?php the_field('expiry'); ?> | <a href="<?php echo get_permalink("101");?>">Terms and Conditions</a>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="package-border"><img src="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/toolbox/images/package-bg-2.png"/></div>
        <div class="package-get">What you get</div>
        <?php the_field('treatments'); ?>
        <div class="package-cost">
            R <?php the_field('cost'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.entry-content .package-container > div {
    padding:20px 40px;
    min-height: 250px;
}

.entry-content .package-container .package-border {
    position: absolute;
    display:table-cell;
    margin-left: -65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

I want the two images in .package-border to line up vertically in the middle. However, no matter how I change it, it remains fixed to the top.

What in the above do I need to change to make this work?

EDIT: Made a CodePen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bCjkI

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle of your code and share??

Comment: You should replace the HTML with PHP in it with the rendered HTML

Comment: I can't get jsFiddle to work with bootstrap.css. It doesn't want to break up my div's in 3 columns as it is on my site.

Comment: Updated with a codepen example. Contains more code so it displays exactly like it does on my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give you a working fiddle because you've pasted an html code with php tags in it, but the general rule to center a positioned element with unknown with or height is:

```
.element {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Remember that the positioning will work according to the first parent with `position:relative;` (or the body, if no other element has position: relative;

Comment: Indeed it does. I was styling the image itself. Long day and attempted this at the end... Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 .package-border {
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
```